# My Metro bundler started but not loading, i was stuck from last 10 days

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

After Running

> npx react-native run-android

command successfully run on my machine android application also install on my mobile app and the metro server started but not loading anything. after manually pressing ctrl + R showing a message like the one below. I have attached a screenshot for your reference.

> warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your metro bundle is running on 8081 port.

**yarn start --port 8081**

**adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081**

Try this above 2 commands, I hope this will help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your phone/simulator to talk to Metro Bundler.

There is a command line tool called 'adb'.  You need to install that into your local terminal. Then do yourself a favor and add it to your $PATH so you can call `adb` from anywhere. In my case I use zsh so I edited my ~/.zshrc file (your file might be ~/.bash_profile or other).

`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{my_user_directory}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/`

Then source the file: `source ~/.zshrc`

Now run in your terminal: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

I usually run this right after I start up the simulator but before my app actually loads up.